# Change background colour for first item in listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview which when a user clicks on an item changes that items background colour, however what I also need it to do is set the first item in the view to have the background colour so it is the 'default' item if the user does not click anything.

My onclick for the listview looks like:

```
list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    View row = null;
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                        imageURL = (String) (list1.getItemAtPosition(position));
                        if (row != null) {
                            row.setBackgroundResource(0);
                        }
                        row = v;
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.selected);

                    }
                });
```

and my current list adapter looks like:

```
class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        private ArrayList<String> items;

        public MyListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                ArrayList<String> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.image_row_layout, null);
            }
            String o = items.get(position);
            if (o != null) {
                SmartImageView tt = (SmartImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.smallimage);
                if (tt != null) {
                    tt.setImageUrl(o);

                }
            }
            return v;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could check if(position == 0) in getView and set the background color of v (if no other item is selected)

Answer (score 2):

dont change the background of the row manually in your onItemClick because when that specific row gets recycled it will show the background of another row that was not selected as the color you changed it too.

instead create a selector with the different states for your background and use [setItemChecked](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setItemChecked%28int,%20boolean%29) to indicate what row is checked and the listview will manage if the background should be a different color or not